# Psion Crystal Attack Powers vs. Incorporeal?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics, incorporeal, damage-types

There are several crystal attacking powers for psions. They inflict damage along the lines of slashing and piercing.

The incorporeal subtype says this:

> An incorporeal creature has no physical body. It can be harmed only by
> other incorporeal creatures, magic weapons or creatures that strike as
> magic weapons, and spells, **spell-like abilities, or supernatural
> abilities**. It is immune to all nonmagical attack forms. Even when
> hit by spells or magic weapons, it has a 50% chance to ignore any
> damage from a corporeal source (except for positive energy, negative
> energy, force effects such as magic missile, or attacks made with
> ghost touch weapons). Although it is not a magical attack, holy water
> can affect incorporeal undead, but a hit with holy water has a 50%
> chance of not affecting an incorporeal creature.

The psionic crystal type (Complete Psionics p. 79) says this:

> METACREATIVITY AND DAMAGE REDUCTION Any damage-dealing metacreativity
> power that specifies piercing, slashing, or bludgeoning damage does
> not automatically overcome a creature’s damage reduction. Such powers
> include crystal shard (EPH 89), hail of crystals (EPH 111), swarm of
> crystals (EPH 134), burrowing bonds (page 79), and crystalstorm (page
> 81).

We are using magical transparency rules. So what gives? Does a crystal manifested as an attack that then vanishes constitute one of those attacks with a 50% chance of passing through, as with the other spell attacks, or is it considered a real non magical non spell attack that simply fails 100% of the time?

Does a psionic power have to apply Power Resistance=Yes in the descriptor in order to get that 50% chance of doing damage to incorporeal creatures?

Here's the power that came into question:

> **Crystal Shard** Metacreativity (Creation)
>
> Level:    Psion/Wilder 1
>
> Display:  Auditory and material
>
> Manifesting Time:     1 standard action
>
> Range:    Close (25 ft. + 5 ft./2 levels)
>
> Target:   Ray
>
> Duration:     Instantaneous
>
> Saving Throw:     None
>
> Power Resistance:     No
>
> Power Points:     1
>
> Upon manifesting this power, you propel a razor-sharp crystal shard at
> your target. You must succeed on a ranged touch attack with the ray to
> deal damage to a target. The ray deals 1d6 points of piercing damage.
>
> Augment: For every additional power point you spend, this power’s
> damage increases by 1d6 points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Damage Reduction](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damageReduction) is not the same thing as the [Incorporeal Subtype](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype)'s immunity to damage.

[Power Resistance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#powerResistance) and its magic equivalent [Spell Resistance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellResistance) are wholly different from both.

The short version is:

- [Damage Reduction](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damageReduction) (DR) reduces the amount of damage that a creature takes from weapon-like attacks.

  - Frequently, DR can be overcome by some combination of factors; it's written as "DR {amount}/{stuff that bypasses DR}" (eg., "DR 5/-" is 5 points of DR that nothing bypasses, "DR 5/magic" is 5 points that a magic weapon-like attack will bypass, and "DR 5/magic and cold iron" is 5 points of DR that can only be bypassed by a weapon-like attack that is both magical and cold iron; "DR 5/magic or cold iron" would allow a non-magical cold iron weapon to bypass the DR or any magical weapon to bypass it).
  - DR reduces the amount of damage that an attack does, to a minimum of zero (eg., an attack that does 3 points of damage against a foe with DR 5/- would do zero damage).
  - DR applies against weapon-like attacks; that is, any attack or effect that deals bludgeoning, piercing, and/or slashing damage.
- An [Incorporeal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype) creature's immunity to damage is not DR; rather, it's an ability that acts similarly to DR but is much better.
- [Spell Resistance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellResistance) and [Power Resistance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#powerResistance) represent a creature's ability to shrug off magical effects; the caster (manifester) needs to succeed on a caster level check to affect the creature at all. It's written as "SR {caster level check DC}".

[Crystal Shard](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/crystalShard.htm) does not offer [PR](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#powerResistance), so those rules don't affect the question of its effect on [incorporeal creatures](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype). It's a weapon-like attack (since it does piercing damage), so [DR](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damageReduction) would apply. It's also a "spell" (using magical transparency), so the incorporeal creature's immunity to mundane damage does not apply; the 50% chance of not taking damage does, however, unless the manifester has some method of bypassing it (similar to the [Ghost Touch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#ghostTouchWeapon) weapon ability).

Short version: [Crystal Shard](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/crystalShard.htm) will hurt [Incorporeal Creature](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype)s 50 percent of the time that the ranged touch attack hits (there are probably caveats about a specific creature, though, because it's D&D).